# Lmer in r: Repeated Measures Model correctly defined? (HLM)

Tags: r, lme4, mixed-models

This is my first time working with `lmer` and I'm not sure whether I'm doing the right thing.
My data is a repeated measures data with the Variables ID, Season, Start Time Loudness and Train. The Loudness (in db) was measured at several locations (ID) for 4 times, once in every Season and at different Times. Train gives the distance from each location to the nearest train station. There are some missing values in my data, which I removed, so it's not a balanced design.

Here is an example:

```
df <- data.frame(Id  = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2), 
   Loudness = c(12.4, 12.5, 35.4, 23.3, 12.5, 34.5, 14.5, 16.3),
   Season = c("Spring", "Summer", "Fall", "Winter", "Spring", "Summer", "Fall", "Winter"),
   Start_Time = c("09:32:23", "09:37:38", "10:12:34", "11:38:48", 
    "12:38:35", "12:38:50", "14:49:56", "13:38:45"), 
   Train = c(rep(12.4, 4), rep(18.4, 4)))
```

I recoded Season from 0 to 3 and Start_Time from 0 to 2 (morning, noon, afternoon) and transformed both of them into factors.

As I'm trying to understand my model from a hierarchical linear model standpoint, the variables Loudness, Season and Start_Time would be my level 1 variables and Train as well as ID would be my level 2 variables.

I'm now trying to calculate the following model in R, so that I can have a random effect for Season. The interaction between Start Time and Season should also be calculated and there is another interaction for Train, given that it is a level 2 variable.

`Model <- lmer(Loudness ~ Season * Start_Time * Train + (Season|ID), data = df)`

But when calculating this I get the following warning:

`Error: number of observations (=2748) <= number of random effects (=2920) for term (Season | ID); the random-effects parameters and the residual variance (or scale parameter) are probably unidentifiable`

I realized that I don't get a warning when I transform Season into a numerical variable.
My question is: What difference does it make when I transform Season into a numerical variable and why doesn't R calculate the model when Season is a factor. Also am I defining the model correctly, given that I'm assuming Train to be my level 2 variable?
I'm looking forward to your answers :).

Comment: is there a missing `+` in your formula before `(Season|ID)`?  (do you have a `data` argument?)  You haven't shown us `ID` in your data example ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic issue is that there is only a single observation per Season/ID combination, so your random effect is confounded with the residual variance (which also has one random iid Gaussian value per observation). If you transform Season into a numerical variable, you're fitting a random-slopes model which will have only two parameters (slope and intercept) per group, rather than 4 (intercept and three seasonal contrast parameters).

The model otherwise looks sensible.

You have a variety of choices:

- you can use `control = lmerControl(check.nobs.vs.nRE = "ignore")` (possibly also including `check.nobs.vs.nlev = "ignore"`) to ignore the confounding; your variance estimate will be non-unique, but everything else will probably work OK
- you could suppress the residual variance term; this isn't possible with `lmer`, but you could use `glmmTMB` (`dispformula = ~0`) or you could use `lme` (`lmeControl(sigma = [small non-zero number])`) or `blme` (with `resid.prior` set to a small non-zero value)
- you could leave out the `Season` term in the random effect (i.e. `(1|ID)`); your model will now correspond to a *homogeneous compound symmetric* model (the same variance in the RE for every season, and the same correlation for every pair of seasonal effects), which is probably still reasonable

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer! I now defined Season and Start_Time as nuemric variables. But I now get the warning that my model didn't converge when I try to run this in r: `lmer(Loudness ~ Season * Start_Time + (Start_Time|ObjectID), data = df, REML=T )` Do you know what could be the reason for that?

Comment: There is **lots** of material around for what to do about convergence issues in `lmer`. Try looking at the "troubleshooting" or "convergence" help pages, or searching on Stack Overflow, or the GLMM FAQ, or ... if you can't find an answer, please post a new question with a [mcve] ...